# Create an array of arrays for each character and the corresponding character count for a given string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

**Assignment Question**
I was tasked to write a function that does the following: takes an input as an array and returns an array of arrays as such:

```
charFrequency("mississippi") ===
[ ['m', 1],
  ['i', 4],
  ['s', 4],
  ['p', 2]
]
```

Here is my code. What I'm trying to do is that for each character in the string, check if that character matches one of the characters in the result array, if so, increment the value associated with that character by 1, if not, create a new array of that character, and start it off by 1. I would like to incorporate forEach!

```
function charFrequency(string) {
  var result = [];
  string.forEach(function(char) {
    if ((string[char] === (result.forEach(function(element) {return element};)) {
      result[element][1] ++;
    } else {
      result.push([result[element], 1]);
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to incorporate `forEach` when it doesn't fit??? If at all, you might want to use `some`.

Comment: @thefourtheye - sorry, i just don't know why the code wasn't working. i thought it was the first if statement, but i wasn't sure if i was taking the right approach

Comment: @Bergi it was just a requirement that was a part of the problem

Comment: in other words, this is a homework assignment, not a practical problem.

Comment: @claies yeah, am i not allowed to ask these questions on SO?

Comment: nothing *wrong* with asking homework questions, but the people who ask and answer questions on this site are professionals, and generally try to look for the most efficient way to do things; your professors have you do things to understand concepts, not because of efficiency.  It leads to you rejecting answers because they don't have the concepts you are trying to learn, or worse, you taking code to class and not passing because you didn't apply the concepts being taught...

Comment: see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: @Claies i'm self-taught and just trying to be resourceful since there's no one else i can ask questions to

Comment: not knocking your question, or that it's a homework assignment, just making it clear that it is, so the answers you get are more focused.

Comment: @Claies ok thanks - i'll clarify that in my future questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using an object makes it much simpler and cleaner, but you can convert the object to a 2-col array afterwards if you really need to:

```
function charFrequency(string) {
  var result = {};
  [].forEach.call(string, function(char) {
    if (!result[char]) result[char]=0; //first time seen? set 0, so we can increment
    result[char]++; // increment the char count
  });
  return result;
}

charFrequency("mississippi"); // == {m: 1, i: 4, s: 4, p: 2}
```

Comment: thanks! i think that's what i'll do. the task was just to return an array of arrays, but i'm going to take this approach and turn it into an array of arrays.

Comment: Two suggestions: `reduce` instead of `forEach` and `||` instead of `if`.

Comment: @georg: reduce would work well, but OP wanted forEach. in terms of the default vs if, you don't save much code, and you arguably lose readability by using the default operator. its also usually more expensive to set than get, and the default operator would read and set a redundant value each time instead of reading the value and potentially setting... all in all, it's not a big deal either way, they both work well in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better if you just use a object and return something like this: {m: 1, i: 4, s: 4, p: 2}

I implemented it here: https://jsfiddle.net/muLco121/

```
function charFrequency(myText) 
{ 
    var charFrequencyObject = {};
    for(var i=0; i<myText.length; i++) 
    {
        var char = myText[i];
        if(!charFrequencyObject[char]) 
        {
            charFrequencyObject[char] = 1;
        } else {
            charFrequencyObject[char]++;
        }
    }
    return charFrequencyObject;
}


console.log( charFrequency("mississippi") );
```